# How to skip executable files when merging with Meld?

Tags: merge, binary-data, meld

I use Linux, C++ and Meld. I want to compare two directories, but only some files from it: I want to merge the source code, but I don't want to merge the binary files. I can easily skip the object files (*.o), but I can't find a way to skip the executable files, because they have no extension. Any ideas?